# Count how many rows have the same value but if the ID are different count it separate

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Here's my query,

```
Select r.coupon_id,  c.who_added, c.coupon_name, r.when_added
From redeemed_coupons r 
JOIN coupon c on r.coupon_id = c.coupon_id AND c.who_added = 1 
AND r.when_added BETWEEN 1602827745 AND 1613084678 ORDER BY r.when_added
```

[image: now]

How do I get the count of a row with same value of `when_added` but if the `coupon_id` is different you have to count it separately even if you have same `when_added`

the result go like this:

```
|coupon_id|who_added|coupon_name|when_added| total_count|
|---------|---------------------------------------------|
|    1    |    1    |Free Appe. |1602827745|      1     |
|    2    |    1    |Free Appe. |1602835586|      1     |
|    3    |    1    |10% off    |1603084636|      1     |
|    4    |    1    |50% off    |1603084678|      2     |
```

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you just want a count using a window function?

```
select r.coupon_id, c.who_added, c.coupon_name, r.when_added,
       count(*) over (partition by r.coupon_id, r.when_added) as cnt
from redeemed_coupons r join
     coupon c
     on r.coupon_id = c.coupon_id and
        c.who_added = 1 and
        r.when_added BETWEEN 1602827745 AND 1613084678
order by r.when_added ;
```

EDIT:

In older versions of MySQL, you can use a correlated subquery:

```
select r.coupon_id, c.who_added, c.coupon_name, r.when_added,
       (select count(*) 
        from redeemed_coupons r2 join
             coupon c2
             on r2.coupon_id = c2.coupon_id and
                c2.who_added = 1 and
                r2.when_added BETWEEN 1602827745 AND 1613084678
        where r2.when_added = r.when_added
      )
from redeemed_coupons r join
     coupon c
     on r.coupon_id = c.coupon_id and
        c.who_added = 1 and
        r.when_added BETWEEN 1602827745 AND 1613084678
order by r.when_added ;
```

Note that this is much less efficient than using window functions.

Comment: Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(partition by r.when_added) as cnt from redeemed_coupons r join      coupon c   ' at line 2

Comment: @JeremyPaul . . . This query requires MySQL 8.0.

Comment: but my active instance is Mysql 8.0.21

Comment: @JeremyPaul . . . I don't see an obvious error in the syntax.

Comment: oh i see, is there anyway to do this in Mysql 5.0? i think my server is still running at 5.0

Comment: One more thing, i know this is the right answer but I have some issue here

Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'r.when_added' in 'on clause'

Comment: @JeremyPaul . . . MySQL may require that the correlation clause be in the `WHERE` clause.  That is where i would normally put it anyway, so I updated the answer.